# How to study vectors and 3D geometry

Tags: advice

It may be too broad or also offtopic question but I really want to know how to study vectors and 3D geometry. My interest in these topics is very low thus want to gain some .Any suggestions or names of websites providing interactive examples to study these topics.Thanks

Comment: I don't know whether it is available outside or not, but there is a very good BOOK in INDIA by Arihant publications - Vectors and 3D Geometry

Comment: "My interest in these topics is very low" and "I really want to know how to study vectors and 3D geometry" are two contradictory statements. Either you want to study this or you do not. Which is it?

Comment: Want to study...

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, ok, thanks for clearing that up. Why do you want to learn this topic? Maybe you are interested in computer graphics, like creating computer games and such? There are special textbooks for that purpose.

Comment: No basically I am appearing for a competitive exam and many questions come from these geometrical topics so... Can you suggest a way?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to read "A Vector Space Approach to Geometry" by Melvin Hausner. I have personally benefited from this book. Also, "Elementary Vector Geometry" by Seymour Schuster. And, I hope this [PDF](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m200/geometry.pdf) will be a good source of solved examples on the topic for you.